# Why do people assume I am male online when I am female?

Tags: social-psychology, gender

This is something that's never really bothered me too terribly much, but it's interesting how my word choice alone seems to lead people to believe that I am anything other than what I am. Not that have any plans to change the way I write, but I do want to know if there's anything hidden within my manner of speech that leads people to think one way versus another, be it societal expectations, gender norms, or something else.

For reference: See [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/77477/placed-on-work-schedule-despite-approved-time-off-request-is-it-unreasonable-to).

Comment: The same question has been asked and answered here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65793/difference-in-male-vs-female-use-of-the-english-language

Comment: sort of social phenomenon. I've never yet told my gender-identity in SE however I'm male. Surprisingly an user used term 'boy' in a conversation which wandered me too. You didn't used 'feminine' suffix after your pen name such as i, a , ia, etc; didn't used any 'feminine' symbols  like pink or magenta or purple color, or images of flowers or teddy-beers or balloons or paintbrush or round dots or curvy patterns. (Instead you've chosen a technical picture with straightlines and red,yellow,green (warmer) colors.) If I create a fake account with them; people would presume me as woman pretty surely

Comment: btw I'm autism spectrum and took lot of time to understand these 'learned subconscious reflexes' of unwritten social norms. they're pretty irritating to me.

Comment: @what that is a related question but not as exact duplicate. This question seeks more psychological and neurological analysis based on asker's texts as an example.